# replace the payload value of a json file fails

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, curl

I'm trying to replace the json payload in my python code but it is simply not getting replaced.

I have a text file with static values. The text file is first read and stored as an Array in a variable. The payload is used to create a new role for our application.

The rest API is static and the only variable that changes is the values in the payload name.
When i replace the variable in the payload it is not getting impacted and fails.

code

roles.txt file contents

```
["Project Leader Hardware",
"Hardware Engineer",
"Mechanical Engineer",
"Project Leader Mechanics",
"Acoustic Systems Engineer (ASE)",
"Project Leader Transducer",
"System Integrator Hardware",
]
```

```
with open ('roles_final.txt', 'r') as file:
    contents = file.readlines()
    

import requests

json_data = {
    'role': {
        'name': 'f{contents}',
        'external_reference': {
            'service_name': 'string',
            'service_model': 'string',
            'service_model_ref': 'string',
            'status': 'string',
            'external_message': 'string',
            'external_link': 'string',
            'external_status': 'string',
            'locked': True,
        },
    },
}

response = requests.post('https://api.test.com/api/v1/roles', cookies=cookies, headers=headers, json=json_data)
```

Is there a way to iterate over the text values one at a time and replace the values of the name with the one mentioned in the text file. I presume there is a loop missing but unable to point to the exact location where it needs to be pushed into

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the contents as the value of names:

```py
with open ('roles_final.txt', 'r') as file:
    contents = file.readlines()
    

import requests

json_data = {
    'role': {
        'name': contents,
        'external_reference': {
            'service_name': 'string',
            'service_model': 'string',
            'service_model_ref': 'string',
            'status': 'string',
            'external_message': 'string',
            'external_link': 'string',
            'external_status': 'string',
            'locked': True,
        },
    },
}

response = requests.post('https://api.test.com/api/v1/roles', cookies=cookies, headers=headers, json=json_data)
```

Comment: it definitely was not looping and running the rest api ............But added an iterative for loops and changed the code to get that running. But your lead gave me a better way of handling it. :-)